# How do you know what part of the semicircle it is when $\arg\dfrac{z-2}{z+2} = \dfrac\pi2$

Tags: locus

I'm not quite sure how to determine whether the semicircle is below or above the x-axis, because in $\arg\dfrac{z-2}{z+2} = \dfrac\pi2$, it lay above the x-axis with a locus of $(4-x^2)^{1/2}$.

Comment: Do you mean $\arg(\frac{z-2}{z+2})$ ?

Comment: Yeah that = pi/2

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac{x-2-iy}{x+2+iy}=\dfrac{(x-iy)^2-4}{(x+2)^2+y^2}=\dfrac{x^2-y^2-4-2xyi}{(x+2)^2+y^2}$$

Using [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation), $$x^2-y^2-4=0$$ and $$-2xy>0\iff xy<0$$

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH!!!